# Product Integral: Integrability

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given measure spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Then it holds:
$$\int_Y\int_X|\eta(x,y)|\mathrm{d}\mu(x)\mathrm{d}\nu(y)<\infty\implies\int_X|\eta(x,y)|\mathrm{d}\mu(x)<\infty\quad(y\in Y)$$

Can this actually fail?

Comment: no assumption on the product measure?

Comment: @user190080: No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I think I got it:*

For Lebesgue measures:
$$\mu,\nu:\mathcal{B}([0,1])\to\mathbb{R}_+:\quad\mu,\nu:=\lambda$$

Consider the function:
$$\eta:(0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}:(x,y)\mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y}}$$

Then one has:
$$\int_{[0,1]}\eta(x,y)\mathrm{d}\lambda(y)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y}}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x\\=\int_0^1\bigg\{2\sqrt{x^2+1}-2\sqrt{x^2}\mathrm{d}\bigg\}\mathrm{d}x\leq{\int_0^1}2\sqrt{2}\mathrm{d}x=2\sqrt{2}<\infty$$

But one obtains:
$$\int_{[0,1]}\eta(x,0)\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\infty$$

That shows failure.

Comment: but you're example works of course too!

Comment: actually I like your answer a bit more than mine since you have found a computable "example" and you don't set a function artificially to infinity, so +1

Comment: @user190080: Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't hold. In general this looks like [Fubini or Tonelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), but both times we integrate always with respect to each measure, which we don't want to do here in this case.

As already pointed out by Freeze_S, we could apply Fubini/Tonelli in the following example and we therefore would then achieve $0$, but this only holds if we integrate with respect to both measures:

So let's assume we have
$$ \eta(x,y)=f(x)g(y)
$$ 
with $f$ integrable with respect to $\mu(x)$ and $g$ integrable with respect to $\nu(x)$ while we assume $g$ is almost $\nu$-everywhere $0$ but on a nullset $\mathcal{N}$ infinity, so it still holds $\int g(y)\mathrm{d}(\nu(y)=0 $

So now take take a $y^\ast$ from $\mathcal{N}$ and see, that
$$
\int_Y\int_X|\eta(x,y)|\mathrm{d}\mu(x)\mathrm{d}\nu(y)=0 
$$
but $\eta(x,y^\ast)=\infty$, so 
$$
\int_X|\eta(x,y^\ast)|\mathrm{d}\mu(x)\not<\infty
$$
because the integral is not defined.

Comment: Allowing infinite values on a null set seems to easy.

Comment: Also you have integrability w.r.t. propduct measure by Tonelli.

Comment: @Freeze_S hmmm....you're right, I have Tonelli, but this just means that the other iterated integral exists and that they are equal, but the Lemma only applies when I really take the double integral - which you don't want. But I definitely need to change what I wrote in the beginning.